# plotting with nan in samples with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
x = numpy.arange(0.0, 5, 1)
y = numpy.array([np.nan,2,3,4,5])
plt.plot(x,y)
```

I am trying to plot, but the graph always starts with 1 instead of 0. Can I force it to start with 0 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set axis limits in matplotlib graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268277/set-axis-limits-in-matplotlib-graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to set the minimum x value to 0:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = numpy.arange(0.0, 5, 1)
y = numpy.array([numpy.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5])
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim(xmin=0)
plt.show()
```

You can do the same for the y-axis by using `ylim`:

```
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
```

Comment: oh.. was indeed so simple.. I was thinking that there is some problem with the array.